# BigQuery: new users do not match firebase console data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a raw BigQuery dataset connected to a Firebase Analytics project. I suppose it contains the same data Firebase reports are based upon.

I have about 10k app installs in September in Firebase console.

Although, when I query the raw data for the users whose pseudo_id first appeared in September, I got just a half of that.

Here's the query, it's very simple:

```
select min(dt_min) as dt_min, count(1) as user_cnt, sum(pur) as user_purch from (
select user_pseudo_id, max(case when event_name='in_app_purchase' then 1 else 0 end) as pur, min(event_date) as dt_min from `analytics_222636927.events_*`
group by  user_pseudo_id) as t_stat
where dt_min>='20200901'
```

Do you have any clue why the results don't match?

Thanks in advance!
WBR, Anton.